# Trim function within a Where Clause

Tags: c#, linq

Say you have a Collection of items

```
    IList<string> items = List<string>();
```

And you want to search each element against some search term: *term*. If you performed a Trim() within the Where clause as follows, would the trim operation occur for each element in the sequence, or would it be compiled once and then used to check against the elements?

```
    items.Where(o => o.Contains(term.Trim())).ToList();
```

This question was based on a LINQ to SQL statement but I have simplified it. (Unsure if compiling to SQL would make any difference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's worth noting here a difference between object-based linq that uses `Func<…>` and expression-based linq that uses `Expression<Func<…>>`.

In object-based linq, `o => o.Contains(term.Trim())` is used as a `Func<string, bool>`. We can reason about it as such.

Now, considering `o => o.Contains(term.Trim())` as such. It has a captured variable `term` on which the method `Trim()` is called. And so that's just what happens.

There are three reasons why `Trim()` must be called every time.

1. Considering just this delegate, we do not know that `Trim()` is pure and hence would always return the same value for the same object.
2. Considering just this delegate we do not know that `term` is immutable, and so `Trim()` would return the same value for the same object even if we did know it was pure.
3. Considering just this delegate, We don't know that the captured variable isn't changed between calls.

In all a delegate can be reasoned about pretty much like a method if we consider the captured variables to be mutable fields. If you looked at:

```
class SomeClass
{
  public string term;
  public bool Predicate(string o)
  {
    return o.Contains(term.Trim());
  }
}
```

You wouldn't expect the call to `Trim()` to be cached for reasons analogous to the three reasons above.

Now, with expression-based linq, such as Linq2SQL or EF it's a bit different.

In this case `o => o.Contains(term.Trim())` is used as a `Expression<Func<string, bool>>`, and there's a lot more variety in what a provider might do with that.

1. The provider might have special knowledge to know that `term.Trim()` could only ever have the one value, and re-write the expression to `o => o.Contains("/* result of single call to term.Trim() goes here */")`
2. The provider might have no idea what to do with `Trim()` and throw an exception.
3. The provider might not do anything special in how it turns `term.Trim()` into SQL, but the database processing that SQL in turn might itself realise it needs only to be calculated once, and so do so.
4. None of the above might happen, with it being essentially the same as the object-based case.

Expressions handling is a lot more flexible in terms of what may or may not happen to optimise the handling.

Answer (score 4):

If it's in memory, then *yes*, it is called every time. A simple test:

```
public static class BLah
{
    public static string DoTrim(this string item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("called");
        return item.Trim();
    }
}

IList<string> items = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
items.Where(o => o.Contains(term.DoTrim()));
```

Prints out 'called' 3 times.

However, when executing on the database, it's *completely up to the ORM* to decide how to generate the SQL, which may or may not call `TRIM()` as part of the query. The only way to know is to test it and see what SQL it generates.

For Linq2Sql, it does *not* run the trim multiple times. For example:

```
string term = "a b ";
Warehouses.Where(w => w.AdminComment.Contains(term.DoTrim()));
```

Produces

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = '%a b%'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Name], [t0].[AdminComment], [t0].[AddressId]
FROM [Warehouse] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[AdminComment] LIKE @p0
```

Comment: "However, when executing on the database, it's completely up to the ORM to decide how to generate the SQL, which may or may not call TRIM() as part of the query. "
I have a query which doesn't work with Trim(). I hope that was the case.

Answer (score 1):

Why should the result of `term.Trim` be cached in any way? There is no runtime-magic included that would imply that the result of this operation never changes and therefore the operation is always executed for every single element. To improve this you may cache the result yourself:

```
var test = term.Trim();
items.Where(o => o.Contains(test).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not an L2S IQueryable call. If it were a proper L2S call, then it would be converted to:

field LIKE @p0

where @p0 set to %term%

For example, with Northwind sample database:

```
var term = "USA";
var items = db.Customers
   .Where(c => c.Address.Contains( term.Trim() ))
   .ToList();
```

would produce (thanks to LinqPad):

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) SET @p0 = '%USA%'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[CompanyName], [t0].[ContactName], [t0].[ContactTitle], [t0].[Address], [t0].[City], [t0].[Region], [t0].[PostalCode], [t0].[Country], [t0].[Phone], [t0].[Fax]
FROM [Customers] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Address] LIKE @p0
```

Probably you would likely want to write that as this one instead:

```
var term = "USA".Trim();
var items = Customers
   .Where(c => c.Address.Contains( term ))
   .ToList();
```

Generated SQL would be the same.